# Что лучше применять in range(a,b) или >= <= в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Предположим есть 2 варианта кода:

```
if a >= 1 and <= 5:
print("Первый способ")

if a in range(1, 6):
print("Второй способ)
```

Какой из этих вариантов лучше и правильней?

Comment: `a >= 1 and a <= 5`

Comment: Во втором случае сначала выполняется ''range()'', потом идет сравнение с каждым элементом до совпадения. А теперь представьте, что диапазон от 10 до 100000. В первом случае (когда подправим грамматику, см. комментарий gil9red) имеем два, а то и вообще всего одно сравнение, что явно быстрее и менее ресурсозатратно.

Comment: Даже хуже, сначала происходит вызов `range`, потом создаётся объект генератора, потом создаётся объект списка на основе генератора, потом у списка вызывается метод `__contains__`, который обходит все элементы списка, сравнивая каждый с `a`.

Comment: @Эникейщик, не факт что там происходит генерация в том диапазоне (покрайней мере, не для python3). Скорее всего, при операторе `in` проверяется start и end, и step

Comment: @gil9red Ну да, интерпретатор наверняка все это как-нибудь оптимизирует (будь я интерпретатором, я бы именно так и делал).

Comment: @Эникейщик если есть debug symbols для python, то выполнение этого скрипта можно прогнать в gdb и убедиться, что второй вариант порождает шквал вызовов.

Comment: В Python3 range не является генератором. Это специальный тип данных который среди прочего поддерживает проверку на вхождение элемента во множество.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Первый вариант выдаст ошибку:

```
In [2]: a >= 1 and <= 5
  File "<ipython-input-2-034a84f76742>", line 1
    a >= 1 and <= 5
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

По-моему, более идиоматичным и более "читабельным" вариантом будет:

```
if 1 <= a <= 5:
    print('...')
```

этот вариант также будет работать для вещественных чисел...

Как уже сказали в комментариях, вариант `a in range(1, 6)` более затратный с точки зрения ресурсов (особенно для больших чисел), т.к. надо будет пройтись по списку сгенерированных значений для сравнения.

---

Если интересно как именно интерпретируются комманды, то можно воспользоваться модулем [dis (disassemble)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html):

```
In [5]: import dis

In [6]: dis.dis('1 <= a <= 5')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              4 DUP_TOP
              6 ROT_THREE
              8 COMPARE_OP               1 (<=)
             10 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    18
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 (5)
             14 COMPARE_OP               1 (<=)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   18 ROT_TWO
             20 POP_TOP
             22 RETURN_VALUE

In [7]: dis.dis('a in range(1, 6)')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (range)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (6)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             10 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             12 RETURN_VALUE

In [8]: dis.dis('1 <= a and a <= 5')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              4 COMPARE_OP               1 (<=)
              6 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    14
              8 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (5)
             12 COMPARE_OP               1 (<=)
        >>   14 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: А что скажете о range?

Comment: @entithat, немного дополнил ответ...